# Find out which port a USB connection is coming from

Tags: c#, java, c++, c, usb

I need to have a program that detects which USB port flash drives are plugged into. I can find if a certain drive is connected or not, but not where it is.

For Example, when Drive 1 gets connected to USB port 1, I need to be able to say Drive 1 connected to Port 1. Is there anyway to do this in Java, C#, c++, c or any other language. I am comfortable with any of those languages.

Here is what I had with Java. This tells me when Drive D, or Drive F is connected but not in what port. Thanks in advance for any help.

```
public class FindDrive
{

public static void main(String[] args)
{
String[] letters = new String[]{ "A", "B", "C", "D", "E", "F", "G", "H", "I"};
File[] drives = new File[letters.length];
boolean[] isDrive = new boolean[letters.length];

// init the file objects and the initial drive state
for ( int i = 0; i < letters.length; ++i )
    {
    drives[i] = new File(letters[i]+":/");

    isDrive[i] = drives[i].canRead();
    }

 System.out.println("FindDrive: waiting for devices...");

 // loop indefinitely
 while(true)
    {
    // check each drive 
    for ( int i = 0; i < letters.length; ++i )
        {
        boolean pluggedIn = drives[i].canRead();

        // if the state has changed output a message
        if ( pluggedIn != isDrive[i] )
            {
            if ( pluggedIn )
                System.out.println("Drive "+letters[i]+" has been plugged in");
            else
                System.out.println("Drive "+letters[i]+" has been unplugged");

            isDrive[i] = pluggedIn;
            }
        }

    // wait before looping
    try { Thread.sleep(100); }
    catch (InterruptedException e) { /* do nothing */ }

    }
}
}
```

If I was not clear enough, please let me know. I really need to find the solution to this.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like [usb4java](http://usb4java.org/) can do what you want. Look at the [high-level API](http://javax-usb.sourceforge.net/jdoc/), specifically the [USBDevice#getParentPort()](http://javax-usb.sourceforge.net/jdoc/javax/usb/UsbDevice.html#getParentUsbPort%28%29) method.

Here's some [example code](https://github.com/usb4java/usb4java-javax-examples/blob/master/src/main/java/org/usb4java/javax/examples/DumpDevices.java) to get you started.

Comment: Thanks! Will have a look

Comment: It appears I have the same problem. I need to be able to tell which physical port the connection is coming from.

Comment: `USBDevice#getParentPort()` returns an instance of `UsbPort`. `UsbPort` exposes a method called `getPortNumber()` that, according to the docs, "Gets the number of this port.
Port numbers are 1-based, not 0-based; see the USB 1.1 specification table 11.8 offset 7. Since the number is 1-based, the first port on a hub has port number 1. There is a maximum of 255 ports on a single hub (so the maximum port number is 255)"

That sounds like what you want. Is it not?